# I need help reading a status field from XML

Tags: xml, delphi, delphi-7

I need to read the `status` field in this XML text, using Delphi 7.

This XML is inside a `TMemo`:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<licensecloud>
     <request_id>665675780</request_id>
     <request_timestamp>8/4/2018 15:47:44</request_timestamp>
     <request_status>OK</request_status>
     <error_num>0</error_num>
     <error_msg></error_msg>
     <error_desc></error_desc>
     <license>
          <key>a6gdfg567c79afd429d872d</key>
          <dashed>A6589-dfg46D429-D872D</dashed>
          <status>ACTIVE</status>
<trial>no</trial>
<expires/>
```

So far, I'm doing this with no result, I'm not getting anything:

```pascal
Uses XMLDoc, XMLIntf;

procedure TForm1.BitBtn1Click(Sender: TObject);
var
  XmlFile : TXMLDocument;
  Doc: IXMLDocument;
  MainNode, CustomerNode : IXMLNode;
  i : Integer;
  XMLPath : string;
begin
  Doc := LoadXMLData(Memo1.Text);
  try
   // XmlFile.LoadFromFile(XMLPath);
    Doc.Active := True;
    MainNode := Doc.DocumentElement;

    for i:=0 to MainNode.ChildNodes['licensecloud'].ChildNodes.Count-1 do
    begin
      CustomerNode := MainNode.ChildNodes['licensecloud'].ChildNodes[i];
      //Here you can get any imformation
      ShowMessage(CustomerNode.ChildNodes['status'].Text);

      //ShowMessage(CustomerNode.ChildNodes['address_line_1'].Text);
    end;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(XmlFile);
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Your xml is invalid. There are missing end tags (`</license>` and `</licensecloud>`). Valid xml:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <licensecloud>
       <request_id>665675780</request_id>
       <request_timestamp>8/4/2018 15:47:44</request_timestamp>
       <request_status>OK</request_status>
       <error_num>0</error_num>
       <error_msg></error_msg>
       <error_desc></error_desc>
       <license>
           <key>a6gdfg567c79afd429d872d</key>
           <dashed>A6589-dfg46D429-D872D</dashed>
           <status>ACTIVE</status>
       </license>
       <trial>no</trial>
       <expires/>
   </licensecloud>
   ```
2. MainNode is `<licensecloud>`. `MainNode.ChildNodes['licensecloud']` is incorrect. Correct code:

   ```
   procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
   var
     XmlFile : TXMLDocument;
     Doc: IXMLDocument;
     MainNode, CustomerNode : IXMLNode;
     i : Integer;
     XMLPath : string;
   begin


     Doc := LoadXMLData(Memo1.Text);
     try
      // XmlFile.LoadFromFile(XMLPath);
       Doc.Active := True;
       MainNode := Doc.DocumentElement;

       ShowMessage(MainNode.ChildNodes['license'].ChildNodes['status'].Text);
     finally
       FreeAndNil(XmlFile);
     end;
   end;
   ```